# Как войти в пользователя вслепую используя клаву?

Tags: ubuntu

Вопрос к линуксоидам!

Ноутбук `Acer V3-551G`, с `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` на борту, дисплей на ноуте мертвый, посему использую сторонние моники чтобы работать. Сейчас я не у себя дома, и монитор к которому я подключился имеет разрешение `1280х1024` точек, ноутбук при входе в пользователя не покажет абсолютно ничего на второй монитор, поскольку тот не имеет разрешения идентичного с родным на ноуте. Необходимо войти в пользователя, чтобы я смог продолжить   эксплуатировать аппаратуру. Вопрос, используя клаву, как в слепую войти в юзера? Левые советы не давайте, не забивайте тему, вдруг кому ещё пригодится!

Comment: ctrl+alt+F1 если на втором мониторе всё еще ничего:    login    password    apt-get -y install ssh    /etc/init.d/ssh restartпотом со второй машины подсоединяйтесь через ssh и настраивайте второй монитор.

Answer (score 1):

По-умолчанию, при загрузке этой версии Ubuntu, курсор автоматически устанавливается в поле ввода пароля - вводите пароль и вот Вам доступ к системе. Если пользователей несколько, то автоматически курсор устанавливается в поле ввода пароля последнего входившего в систему пользователя.

Я бы на Вашем месте решил уже вопрос с переносом данных на другое железо, ибо так работать - это мазохизм.

Еще как вариант удаленное управление встроенными средствами этой системы (VNC, ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Если ты подключил другой монитор, он должен работать даже если он другого разрешения чем стандартный. Проблема не в нём, возможно что-то не работает.